# server refused the connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a rails project on my dev machine and uploaded it to my VPS.
I've corrected all of the configuration errors, installed and configured postgres. I worked out all of the database user and role issues. Now I go to my browser to see if it works and here is the error I get:

```
Google Chrome's connection attempt to dev.mysite.com was rejected
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.
```

I also noticed that I entered dev.mysite.com and it comes back in the address bar https:// dev.mysite.com/  I'm guessing this could be a clue.

How should I go about troubleshooting and correcting this issue?

I tried `curl -I http:// dev.mysite.com`
and I get back:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 301
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Location: https:// dev.mysite.com/
Date: Fri, 15 Mar 2013 13:14:54 GMT
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Server: nginx/1.0.11 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it is odd that curl and chrome report different errors?  does chrome connect to 80 and then fail on the redirect?  Do you have a config setting in either your rails app to force ssl? ( config.force_ssl ) or something in nginx that does that?  If you do a netstat -an i am assuming that your server is listening only on 80 and no 443, henceh the connection refused.

Comment: have you explicitly configured your server to only accept https (ssl) secured connexions ?

Comment: netstat -an produces:                                            `code`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address      Foreign Address   State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53570    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6117       0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25         0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN

Comment: yes I do have config.force_ssl = true

Comment: have you explicitly configured your server to only accept https (ssl) secured connections ? explicitly I don't believe so. I am not sure.

Comment: I added: "listen 443 default_server ssl;" to my nginx configuration and restarted nginx. No change.

Comment: looks like a need an ssl_certificate at this point

Comment: config.force_ssl = true tells rails to redirect all to ssl. also you will need to setup the certs and the like to get nginx to actually listen on ssl

Comment: you can generate a self signed ssl cert to use, there are many tutorials online on howto do that.  To test (if you don't need ssl) you can set force_ssl = false and redeploy.

Comment: I set the force_ssl = false. Didn't make a difference. I guess there is something else forcing ssl. Do I have to take out listen 443 default_server ssl; as well?

Comment: Sorry I don't know nginx that well.  Try the curl again,  Perhaps ngnix isn't listening on 80 anymore. Also it wouldn't hurt to revert to the nginx config where you got the redirect

Comment: I got the certs to work. Now I'm hitting the rails app. No errors in app's error log file but I get "We're Sorry, But Something Went Wrong" Now I need to troubleshoot the app. Huge Thanks to you Doon.

Comment: All issues resolved. YES! Had to run bundle exec rake assets:precompile to correct the app error.